# find grep exec, result

Tags: 14.04, command-line, grep, find, gnu

If I run the following command

```
find ./dir -type f -newermt 2017-04-01 ! -newermt 2018-06-30 -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td  %TH:%TM:%.2TS   %p\n" -exec grep -E -l "pattern" {} \; | sort -n;
```

will return this:

```
./dir_2/01.py</br>
./dir_2/03.py</br>
./dir_2/05.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:44:55   ./dir_2/01.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:03   ./dir_2/02.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:13   ./dir_2/03.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:21   ./dir_2/04.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:28   ./dir_2/05.py</br>
```

but I would like to have this:
(because only these three file contain "pattern")
(including date and timestamp)

```
2018/05/08  08:44:55   ./dir_2/01.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:13   ./dir_2/03.py</br>
2018/05/08  08:45:28   ./dir_2/05.py</br>
```

I use Ubuntu version: 14.04.5 LTS trusty
and find version (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

Putting the `-exec grep [...]` before the `-printf` and sending the `stdout` of `grep` to `/dev/null` (needs `sh -c`) works well:

```bsh
find ./dir -type f -newermt 2017-04-01 ! -newermt 2018-06-30 \
  -exec sh -c 'grep -E -l "pattern" "{}" 1>/dev/null' \; \
  -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td  %TH:%TM:%.2TS   %p\0" | \
sort -z -n | tr '\0' '\n'
```

---

Thanks to your question I learned something new. I did not even know that it is possible to filter `find` results like that.

Another option would be to use some piping and `xargs`. First performance tests show me that this is even a little bit faster although I wonder why:

```bsh
find ./dir -type f -newermt 2017-04-01 ! -newermt 2018-06-30 -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -i -P6 grep -E -l "pattern" "{}" | \
  xargs -i find "{}" -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td  %TH:%TM:%.2TS   %p\0" | \
sort -z -n | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(Note the `-P6` --> Running the `grep` command in parallel.)

Comment: If you pipe filenames, always use the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) to make sure the word splitting is done correctly: `find … -print0 | xargs -0 … | sort -z …`

Comment: Good suggestion, updated the answer. But wouldn't `grep` break filenames including a newline anyways ?

Comment: [Let's try!](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gk5b5Thw9X/)

Comment: Wait, do you really need the `tr`? `sort -z` means take the *input* null-delimited, that should (IMO) not affect the output.

Comment: Actually I tried and it didnt work